# How to assert for errors in Playwright?

Tags: typescript, ui-automation, playwright

I'm going nuts trying to assert for a known TimeoutError. I'm currently testing for the Hidden Layers scenario from [UI Testing Playground](http://www.uitestingplayground.com/hiddenlayers) in Playwright Node.js and I would like to know if it's possible to have the TimeoutError not to fail the test, as this is the expectation. I'm pretty new in automating with both Playwright and Typescript.

I have tried multiple methods even making the `clickGreenButton()` method throw the error, but it seems the **expect()** function does not catch it at all.

Method inside the `HiddenLayersPage.ts`:

```
    async clickGreenButton() {
        await this.greenButton.click()
    }
```

Code inside the spec file which is supposed to check that the second click would not be successful as the element to be clicked becomes hidden:

```
await hiddenLayersPage.clickGreenButton();
expect(async () => await hiddenLayersPage.clickGreenButton()).toThrow();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because expect is running your function, but being `async` it’s getting a promise (albeit rejected) back, rather than an error/exception.

So the syntax is a little different. You just need to pass expect the resulting promise, tell it to [unwrap the promise with `.rejects`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#rejects), and then call `toThrow`, like so:

```js
await expect(hiddenLayersPage.clickGreenButton()).rejects.toThrow();
```

Notice the usage/placement of `await`, since you need to await the async matcher, but not await the function since you want the promise.

Comment: Thank you very much! It makes sense now. I used `.rejects` before but didn't `await` for the expect.

Comment: Glad I could help! That’s a common stumble that I see, and have gotten caught on myself ha ha.